# Porque no se seleccione mi radio button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3

Estoy en la realización de un formulario en el cual tengo implementado un par de radio button pero al momento de clickear sobre ellos estos no se seleccione, les comparto a continuación el pequeño fragmento de código que llevo hasta el momento:

```css
.sh_k .sh_sl {
    background-color: #edf7f8;
    color: #282828;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.sh_k .sh_sn {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.sh_k .sh_st {
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 60%;
}

.sh_k .sh_sz {
    width: 100%;
}

.sh_u9 {
    width: 100%!important;
}

.sh_cq {
    font-size: 16px!important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.bpv_cq {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Lettera Text Std;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h5.bpv_cq {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.sh_vm {
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.bpv_cq.bpv_bpx {
    color: #282828;
}

.sh_qj:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.sh_qj {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sh_vb {
    width: 50%!important;
}

.sh_un {
    margin-top: 20px!important;
    width: 31%;
}

.b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq {
    border: 2px solid #0c3970;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: border-color .2s ease;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 20px;
}

.b3n_ag9 label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.b3n_ag9 span {
    color: #3b3f3b;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.b3n_ag9 input {
    opacity: 1;
}

.b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq.b3n_lk:before {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}
.b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq:before {
    background-color: #63666A;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #63666A;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: opacity .2s ease,transform .2s ease;
    width: 12px;
}

.b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq.b3n_lk, .b3n_ag9 .b3n_lq:hover {
    border-color: #63666A;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">
<section class="content">
 <div class="box">
<div class="box-body">
<form class="sh_k" id="form">
              <div class="sh_sn">
                  <div class="sh_u9">
                      <h5 class="sh_cq bpv_cq bpv_bpx">
                        <span class="bpv_bpz">
                            Seleccione una opción
                        </span>
                      </h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sh_qj sh_vm sh_vb">
                      <div class="sh_un b3n_ag9">
                        <label for="elaboracion">
                            <div id="elaboracion-radio" class="b3n_lq">                                    
                               <input name="dna" id="dnaelaboracion" type="radio" value="elaboracion"> 
                            </div>
                            <span>Elaboración</span>                                      
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="sh_un b3n_ag9">
                        <label for="revision">
                            <div id="revision-radio" class="b3n_lq">
                                <input name="dna" id="dnarevision" type="radio" value="revision"> 
                            </div>
                            <span>Revision</span>
                      </label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div> 
              <div class="sh_p0 sh_wl">
                  <button id="submit" type="submit" class="lu_g5 lu_l2">Siguiente</button>
              </div>         
          </form>
              </div>  
                 </div>  

 </section>
  </div>  
  
  </body>
  
  </html>
```

No se si me faltara modificar algo en mi hoja de estilos en alguna de las clases de css, lo único que si noto es que al pasar el cursor por el radio button cambia la tonalidad de su color pero igual no se selecciona.

Es importante resaltar que estoy haciendo uso de **Bootstrap 3.3.7**

**Actualización 1:**

Según parte de los comentarios he realizado un cambio en mi hoja de estilos y es en cambiar la propiedad `opacity` en la siguiente clase `.b3n_ag9 input {opacity: 1;}`.

Con lo anterior ya se refleja el radio button pero el que trae por defecto el navegador que no es lo que estoy buscando, es por esta razón que he creado mi propia hoja de estilos y quiero que se muestre el radio button en base a mi hoja de estilos.

Comment: el tema es que estas aplicando mal tu css, corrige esto y te mostrara tu radio `.b3n_ag9 input {opacity: 1;}`

Comment: @Daniel Lo cambie, pero queda selecciona el radio button que trae por defecto, por esto cree mi hoja de estilos para que no se mostrara el que trae por defecto, alguna otra idea de como solucionarlo ?

Comment: Probaste con [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_visibility.asp)?

Comment: @KBeDev Desconozco la propiedad y no logro entender del todo su funcionalidad, puedes aportarme un ejemplo en base a mi pregunta para darle validez?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la label el for no está bien definido, la de elaboracion debe ser dnaelaboración y la de revision dnarevision, las ids de los inputs.

Para el CSS cambia el input y añade el que te pongo abajo:

```
.b3n_ag9 input {
    appearance: none;
}

.b3n_ag9 input:checked:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background: blue;
  top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Realmetn el botón se activa, pero no lo ves. Ahora al poner el :after, aparecerá en el botón que hayas marcado.
**Editado: es after**

Comment: Con respecto al ultimo comentario que acabas de agregar, te refieres al before o al after ?

Comment: Es after... estos dedos saltarines :)

Comment: Excelente respuesta, clara y concisa.